# Unexpected unindent python

Tags: python

The code below is really annoying me I have looked on stackoverflow and google yet have not found anything and I am a pretty good python programmer and have not as of yet, well until now, found an error that I could not deal with.

I have tried everything but this piece of code is giving me the

```
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

which is weird because the normal error is "undexpected indent" which means as posted many times that its the spacing and how I spaced it so I went through the whole code and nada same error and I put in four spaces correctly and everything still ... nothing. help?

The script is for security reasons and webapp.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#!/usr/bin/python
#Greets:SEC4EVER Members.
import hashlib
import base64
import socket
print"""

___  ___ _    _____ _____
|  \/  || |  |_   _|_   _|
| .  . || |    | |   | |
| |\/| || |    | |   | |
| |  | || |____| |  _| |_
\_|  |_/\_____/\_/  \___/
v0.1
"""


def main():
 print '1 - SHA1  Decrypter'; print
print '2 - MD5  Decrypter'
print '3 - Base64 Decrypter'
print '4 - /etc/passwd users extractor'
print '5 - Port Scanner'
elect = input("Select :")

if select==1:
      sha1()
elif select==2:
      md5()
elif select==3:
      base64()
elif select==4:
      extr()
elif select==5:
      scanner()


def   sha1():
    try:
        sha1 = raw_input("\t\n\nSHA1 Hash:")
        dictionary = open("pwds.txt","r")

        for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
            if hashlib.sha1(passwd).hexdigest() == sha1:

                print("\n\t[OK]"+sha1+" : "+passwd+"\n")


        else:
            print "\n\tFailed; Password not found in dictionary"
            sha1()
    except(IOError):
        print "pwds.txt not found!"
main()
def md5():
    try:
        md5 = raw_input("\t\n\nMD5 Hash:")
        dictionary = open("pwds.txt","r")
        for passwd in dictionary.read().split('\n'):
            if hashlib.md5(passwd).hexdigest() == md5:
                print("\n\t[OK]"+md5+" : "+passwd+"\n")


        else:
            print "\n\tFailed; Password not found in dictionary"
            main()
    except(IOError):
        print "pwds.txt not found!"

def base64():
    try:
     code = raw_input('\n\nBase64:\n\n')
     deco = base64.b64decode(code)
     print '\nDecoded!:\n\n',deco,'\n'
     main()

     def extr():
      try:
       xer = raw_input("/etc/passwd content:")
       passwd_content = xer.split('\n')

       for line in passwd_content :
        y = line.find(':')
       print line[0:y]
       main()

       def scanner():
        try:
         sec4 =raw_input('IP Address:')
         for port in range(1,400):
          s0ck = socket.socket()
         s0ck.settimeout(0.5)
         ip = sec4
         response = s0ck.connect_ex((ip, port))
         if response:
          print ("%d\tclose" %port)
         else:
          print ("%d\topen" %port)
         s0ck.close()

if __name__ !== '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Post the complete traceback.

Comment: sorry at the last line (103)

Comment: Bad indentation, bad structure, bad variable names - well, you're still learning.

Answer (score 5):

In the `base64()` function you've opened multiple `try/except/finally` blocks but you don't have `except` or `finally`, only multiple `try` statements.

Also, if you are planning to continue being a "pretty good python programmer", use 4 spaces for indentation and try to follow [`PEP8`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.

Answer (score 1):

Your `def main()`'s code's indentation is incorrect, it should be:

```
def main():
    print '1 - SHA1  Decrypter'; print
    print '2 - MD5  Decrypter'
    print '3 - Base64 Decrypter'
    print '4 - /etc/passwd users extractor'
    print '5 - Port Scanner'
    elect = input("Select :")

    if select==1:
        sha1()
    elif select==2:
        md5()
    elif select==3:
        base64()
    elif select==4:
        extr()
    elif select==5:
        scanner()
```

Also, please use *atleast* 2 spaces to indent code to aid readablity.

Update your comment:

In that case, it is  as @alexce said, due to unmatched `try` blocks.